# Python Date Issue

Tags: python, function, date

Good morning, everyone, are there any Python functions to get Year, Month, Day, Weekday, Hour information from the following time?

1/21/2015  01:30:22 AM

Thank you very much.
Dennis

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior just some extra reading for the answer

Answer (score 1):

According to the [strftime documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime):

```
from datetime import datetime
mydate = '1/21/2015 01:30:22 AM'
print datetime.strptime(mydate, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

Comment: thank you so much, Sevastien, i got an error message: the original data must be string. I have changed to string already by using: mydate.astype('str'). thank you.